# Invisible cells of UICollectionView stay selected

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

I have a **UICollectionViewController** which uses a custom cell. There is a function get called when the user taps on a cell, to distinguish the selected cell I change the background color of the cell to the green. 
The problem is, when user taps on another cell, the previous one should be unselected, another function will be called. as long as the collectionView is not scrolled it works fine, but when the user scrolls the collectionView and selected one goes out of the visible rect of the screen, my deselect function does not work and there will be two cells with a green background.

It's the demo:

[image]

You can see there is a cell with green background at the top, and another one at the end.

Here are methods for selecting and deselecting cells:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell {
            cell.selectItem()
    }
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, shouldSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    for _cell in collectionView.visibleCells {
        if let __cell = _cell as? CategoryCollectionViewCell {
            __cell.deselectItem()
        }
    }

    if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
        if indexPath.count > 0 {
            if let _cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath.first!) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell {
                _cell.deselectItem()
            }
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Comment: is it multiple selection ?

Comment: @KKRocks No, user should select only one cell.

Comment: ok try my answer

Comment: *"as long as the collectionView is not scrolled it works fine, but when the user scrolls the collectionView..."* It seems most likely you are running into the problem because you are modifying properties of the cell, and not of your data source. When you scroll the collectionView, the cells are re-used. If you do not update your data source, the scrolled cells will not be correct.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I got your issue, simply this happens after scrolling the scroll view, that means the selected become selected and due to reusable cell another cell become selected automatically, well this is a common problem and it happens in UITableView and UIScrollView mostly.

In this view's wherever you have used `if condition` in `datasource` and its `delegate` methods put an `else` part too, and this will  solve your problem.

For example:

```
    if let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems {
        if indexPath.count > 0 {
            if let _cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath.first!) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell {
                _cell.deselectItem()
            }
        }
       else{
         // do something here
       }
    }
    else{
        // do something here
   }
```

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let selectedIndexPath : IndexPath
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell {
            cell.selectItem()
        }

        if let preViousSelectedcell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: selectedIndexPath) as? CategoryCollectionViewCell {
            preViousSelectedcell.deselectItem()
        }
        selectedIndexPath = indexPath

    }
```

Comment: It's the same. still, old selected one is selected.

Comment: this approach is correct you need to check that you have got correct previous cell .